# Remove item from ListView in addListener

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-8

I am having a problem with the following Java program. I am using JavaFX with JDK-1.8u25 on an Ubuntu system. I would like to display a ListView and remove the highlighted entry from the list. I created a list and paired it with an ObservableList to be notified of the listener event. However, it would appear that changing the list by removing an item, "orderOvList.remove (i, i + 1)" below, generates another listener event. So, it seems I am recursing in the body of the listener code. I thought about moving the list element from the nor ordered list, "orderList.remove (i)" but then then ListView isn't updated.

Anyone with any ideas?

The code below crashes after I run it.

Stack Trace:

```
0
0
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1055)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.nextRemove(ListChangeBuilder.java:204)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.nextRemove(ObservableListBase.java:150)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.remove(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:181)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.remove(ObservableListWrapper.java:165)
    at TestListView.lambda$start$0(TestListView.java:32)
    at TestListView$$Lambda$82/921981528.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel$1.onChanged(ListView.java:1245)
    at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.remove(ObservableListWrapper.java:167)
    at TestListView.lambda$start$0(TestListView.java:32)
    at TestListView$$Lambda$82/921981528.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.lambda$new$34(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:67)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase$$Lambda$75/1274395902.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:176)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:142)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)

    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:68)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.select(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:357)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListView.lambda$new$156(ListView.java:374)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListView$$Lambda$74/963851926.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.scene.Node$FocusedProperty.notifyListeners(Node.java:7526)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$13.invalidated(Scene.java:2046)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.setFocusOwner(Scene.java:3891)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.requestFocus(Scene.java:3938)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3877)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.requestFocus(Scene.java:2010)
    at javafx.scene.Node.requestFocus(Node.java:7687)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal.TopMostTraversalEngine.focusAndNotify(TopMostTraversalEngine.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal.TopMostTraversalEngine.traverseToFirst(TopMostTraversalEngine.java:110)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.focusInitial(Scene.java:1980)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.access$3200(Scene.java:144)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.focusCleanup(Scene.java:2330)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2351)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$28(Toolkit.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$$Lambda$154/326451107.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:313)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:340)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:451)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:431)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$363(QuantumToolkit.java:298)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$$Lambda$46/1868350875.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$45(GtkApplication.java:126)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$$Lambda$42/584634336.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Sample code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestListView extends Application {
  @Override
  public void start (Stage stage) {
    List<String> orderList = new ArrayList<String> ();
    ObservableList<String> orderOvList =
      FXCollections.observableList (orderList);
    ListView<String> order = new ListView<String> (orderOvList);

    orderOvList.add ("abc");
    orderOvList.add ("def");
    orderOvList.add ("ghi");
    orderOvList.add ("jkl");

    VBox orderBoxPane = new VBox (6);
    order.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener (
      ov -> {
        int i = order.getSelectionModel ().getSelectedIndex ();

        if (orderOvList.size () >= 0) {
          System.out.println (i);
          orderOvList.remove (i, i + 1);
        }
      });
    orderBoxPane.getChildren ().add (order);

    Scene scene = new Scene (orderBoxPane);
    stage.setTitle ("TestListView");
    stage.setScene (scene);
    stage.show ();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the selected item as soon as the user selects it seems like a strange user experience to want to code. I'm not quite sure what is causing the exception you see, but it's certainly true that the code you execute in the listener will change the selected value, causing a new change event to be raised on the selection model. (I would have expected a `StackOverflowException` rather than an `UnsupportedOperationException`. My guess is that the "nested" change to the list of selected items in the selection model is causing an attempted change to an unmodifiable list.)

If this is really the behavior you want, I would think of it more in terms of a mouse press action - remove the item from the list when the user clicks on it. You can do this by creating a cell factory and registering a mouse listener with the cell you create:

```
order.setCellFactory(lv -> {
    ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(item);
        }
    };
    cell.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        String item = cell.getItem();
        if (item != null) {
            orderOvList.remove(item);

            // ensure nothing selected after removal:
            order.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        }
    });
    return cell ;
});
```

Comment: good solution :-) Just a note on the reason of the exception: recursion in the selectedItems list was my first guess as well, but isn't. Actually it's the modification of the orderList during its firing the change. Client notification of selectedItem -> remove item -> selectionModel is listening to list change and updates itself -> selectedItem firing again -> client notification again: here we are still in the notification of the first remove, thus violating the no-list-modifications-while-being-notified rule